# How do you set the time resolution in Synplify?

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I am generating a 1khz pulse from a 32MHz clock, naturally via a counter. Not a difficult task, so you can imagine my surprise when the result runs at 992Hz...

Simulating the behavioural model of this counter, I can see either correct or incorrect behaviour with no source code changes whatsoever.

The crux of the code is this:

```
constant Clock_Frequency : natural := 32_000_000;
constant Clock_Period : time := 1 sec / Clock_Frequency;
subtype DelayType is natural range 0 to Clock_Frequency;

constant Period : DelayType := 1 ms / Clock_Period;
report "Delay " & DelayType'image(Period) severity NOTE;
```

which reports (in simulation) as follows:

(Xilinx ISIM : as expected)

> at 125 ns: Note: Delay 32000 (/testbench/UUT/UUT/).

(Modelsim : surprise!)

> ** Note: Delay 32258
>       Time: 128 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /testbench/uut/uut

And 32MHz divided by 32258 does indeed give the 992Hz signal I was observing. 
Changing Modelsim's time resolution from its default (presumably 1ns) to 1ps, gives the expected result. So the correct period (31.25 ns) is being rounded down to 31 ns, resulting in incorrect calculation of the delay counter load value.

But the implication is that Synplify (specifically, Actel Edition from MicroSemi Libero 9.1) uses 1ns resolution as its default for time unit resolution.

So, how do I change this to 1ps or 1 fs for more accurate calculations involving time? I can't find any such information in the obvious sources.

Comment: Have you tried something like `1000000000 ps` instead of `1 ms` to force the units into the division? Or is a clunkier workaround an unacceptable solution in this case (assuming that even works - I'm about to try it, out of curiosity)?

Comment: Update: Don't bother, it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: I'm using an integer constant instead as a work-around. If there isn't a time resolution setting, I regard this as a tool bug.

Comment: If IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 were still in effect it tells us (5. Verification) "...As synthesis in general does not recognize the same delays as simulators, the outputs cannot be compared at every simulation time. Rather, they can only be compared at specific simulation times when all transient delays have settled and all active timeout clauses have been exceeded. If the outputs do not match at all comparable times, the synthesis tool shall not be compliant." It sounds like there is an assumption of resolution limit for the target technology and no warning message (an invalid short cut).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer (for the full version of Synplify at least) is to set the option for "Beta Features for VHDL" in the VHDL implementation options.  Or via tcl with `set_option -beta_vhfeatures 1`.

I've tested this with I-2014.03-SP1 on a very simple testcase consisting of a single line architecture asserting time equality.  The assert triggers causing synthesis to fail when the time resolution is wrong.

```
entity test is
  port (a : in bit);
end test;

architecture RTL of test is
begin
  assert 0.1 ns = 100 ps severity failure;
end RTL;
```

The logfile now reports:

```
@W: :  | : Beta Features have been turned ON by enabling the beta features in the project ... 
@N: :  | : Features turned ON: Large Time Resolution
```

and the assert does not trigger.

(I've also tested `0.1 ps = 100 fs` and that still fails, so we're not completely there yet...)

Comment: Sadly, no such option in the version supplied with Libero-9.1sp5, and I'm not about to switch toolchains mid-project even if Libero-11 supports it. Still, it's good to know there's a fix in the pipeline even if we can't all use it. So ... I'm accepting this answer. Please leave the other answer in place as it's actually more correct for my current toolchain, and may save other Libero users some head scratching ... we've got little enough hair left as it is!

Comment: @BrianDrummond - fair enough, I'll leave both.

Answer (score 1):

(Arguably this is not an answer, more a "confirmation of the question" using the full version of the tool). I'll delete it if people would rather...

---

The reference manual for my version of Synplify Pro (I-2014.03-SP1) has this statement in it:

> The support of predefined physical time types includes the expanded
>   range from –2147483647 to +2147483647 with units ranging from
>   femtoseconds, and secondary units ranging up to an hour. Predefined
>   physical time types allow selection of a wide number range
>   representative of time type.

And some example code...

```
 entity test is
    generic (INTERVAL1 : time := 1000 fs;
    INTERVAL2 : time := 1 ps;
    INTERVAL3 : time := 1000 ps;
    INTERVAL4 : time := 1 ns
    );
 -- etc - comparing those values
```

is given.  This implies it's possible!

However, when trying a testcase based on said code it reports

> @N: CD720 :"C:\Synopsys\fpga_I-2014.03-SP1\lib\vhd\std.vhd":123:18:123:21|Setting time resolution to ns

And a very simple testcase fails this assertion:

```
assert 1 ns = 1000 ps severity failure;
```

Which matches the sort of thing you're seeing.

And I can't see how to change the resolution anywhere.

Comment: Your quoted para on page 675 of 1276 (Feb 2013). Resolution limit works by scaling the physical unit.  It would be inherent in the target technology library. Wonder if assert 0.1 ns = 100 ps would work?  Hard to imagine at least not support tenth ns.  Verilog has the timescale directive.

Comment: Just checked - `assert 0.1 ns = 100 ps` also fails

Comment: That tells us it's a VHDL restriction.

Comment: It's not clear to me why that confirms it's a VHDL restriction and not e.g. a "target library"(in this case Atmel/Microsemi) restriction. But if Martin's testcase fails using a generic (non-Atmel) Synplify that would suggest it isn't specific to Atmel editions.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - I now have a better answer - see elsewhere on the page :)

Comment: @BrianDrummond - I think this (non-)answer should be deleted, can you un-accept it (and accept my other one if you think it worthy :)?